# How to query comma delimited field of table to see if number is within the field

Tags: mysql

I want to select rows from a table if a column contains a certain number e.g 981. The data in these columns is either 0, null or in the format below:

```
1007,1035,1189,908,977,974,979,973,982,981,1007
```

How do I phrase this in a query?

Obvious this query below isn't sufficient but I need something similar

```
 SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column`='981'
```

Thanks

Comment: You can try SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%981%'. I don't say this is the best solution but have a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have regular expressions it may work:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` REGEXP  '(^|,)951($|,)'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `IN` clause which [checks whether a value is within a set of values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` IN (1007,1035,1189,979,973,982,981,1007)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` IN ('abc','def','ghi')
```

Please note that cannot mix quoted and unquoted values in the IN list

**EDIT**

I misunderstood the original question. If your column data is like `1007,1035,1189,979,973,982,981,1007` and you're searching for the presence of `981` then you'll have to use `LIKE` instead of `IN`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column LIKE ('%,981,%') OR column LIKE ('%,981') OR column LIKE ('981,%'))
```

to [pattern match](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) the value 981 in the middle, at the end or at the beginning of those comma separated values.

Comment: No that is an example row. The numbers in the row are arbitary.

Comment: `IN` doesn't work to parse comma-separated values in the same column, does it? It will work if you have a single number in a column, but to do a check for a single number in a comma-separated list in a column you'd need to use `LIKE`. (Unless MySQL does something really strange here.)

Comment: Yeah, you're right Ken. I misunderstood the original question.