# splitting data in a table column for search

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I was working with a simple mysql table in php when I came across this problem and I am wondering if there is a solution to this.

The table holds a username and his locations in a comma separated format.

```
 id|user|locations
------------------
 1 |abc | A, B, C
------------------
 2 |xyz | P, Q, R
```

I was wondering if there was any way to write a mysql query so that it would return me a user who has location as A.
Basically if one of the values among the comma separated values match, the record should be returned.

I know it is a better way to store them as separate records, but I was just curious if such a retrieval is possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should consider normalizing the data so you are not storing the comma separated list.

But if you cannot alter the table structure, MySQL has a [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function that can be used to return the rows that match the value you want:

```
select id, user, locations
from yourtable
where find_in_set('A', locations)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82f7a/1)

Comment: Oh that is great. Didnt know mysql had this fucntion. Thanks.

Comment: @AnuragRamdasan Yeah, it is a helpful way to find data in the list.

Answer (score 1):

We think

the following query may help you -

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` REGEXP  '(^|,)A($|,)'

You can have a useful link in -

[How to query comma delimited field of table to see if number is within the field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907856/how-to-query-comma-delimited-field-of-table-to-see-if-number-is-within-the-field)