# REGEP Slowdown query in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

[How to query comma delimited field of table to see if number is within the field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907856/how-to-query-comma-delimited-field-of-table-to-see-if-number-is-within-the-field/25074585#25074585)

I want to select rows from a table if a column contains a certain number e.g 981. The data in these columns is either 0, null or in the format below:

```
1007,1035,1189,908,977,974,979,973,982,981,1007
```

I made a like as in above link. I used `IN ('7','3','12','1','10','13','2')` & it gets only 22K of rows from Table. For the same query If i use `REGEXP '7|3|12|1|10|13|2'` it returs nearly 119K rows from same Table. but REGEXP makes slow the query. is there any method to make my query faster?

Comment: you can create index on that particular column

Comment: That's a problem with such a database design. You should normalize your tables and don't store comma separated lists in just one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `regexp` is confusing values.  So, `7` matches `17` and `77`.  The `in` does what you want.

First, I don't recommend storing values in a comma-delimited list.  If you really have to (like someone who didn't know better designed the database), then use `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(7, list) > 0 or
      find_in_set(3, list) > 0 or
      . . .
```

Alternatively, put delimiters in the `regexp`.  I think it would look like:

```
where concat(',', list, ',') regexp '(,7,)|(,3,)|(,12,)|(,1,)|(,10,)|(,13,)|(,2,)'
```

Comment: +1, @Johnny: have a look at [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd234/2). You don't want the rows with ID 1,2,4 in your result. It shows why an index on that particular column won't help.